# SwiftUI Picker onChange Response is unpredictable

Tags: ios, swiftui, picker

I made a picker like this;

But there is a problem **onChange** does not fire at first selection.

indexList[0] have 0 as value. When other than 0 picked at Picker onChange does not fire
but at following selections it works as it is supposed to work.

Also when Picker list shown at first usage, the first item ticked as it is supposed to be. But when 2nd item is selected it does not fire onChange.

I could not find why.

```
Menu {
      Picker("", selection: $indexList[0]) {
         ForEach(0..<myArray.count, id: \.self) {  index in
              Text(myArray[index])
                    }
                }
             
                .onChange(of: indexList[0],
                          perform: {_ in
                              dump(indexList[0])
                })
             
            } label: {
               customLabel0
            }



var customLabel0: some View{
    HStack {
      VStack(spacing: 10) {
        Text(labels[0])
          .foregroundColor(.black)
             Text(myArray[indexList[0]])
                   .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
             }

           .foregroundColor(.white)
       }
       .frame(width: (width, height: height)
       .background(Color.gray)
       .cornerRadius(5)
   }
```

Comment: When I remove **Menu**  onChange works fine but in that case I can not change Picker text colors etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, it works just fine,
When using Menu placement of onChange have to change.
The shame was there was no documentation and I must try many things.

```
Menu {
  Picker("", selection: $indexList[0]) {
     ForEach(0..<myArray.count, id: \.self) {  index in
          Text(myArray[index])
                }
            }
         
            
         
        } label: {
           customLabel0

        } 
        .onChange(of: indexList[0],
                      perform: {_ in
                          dump(indexList[0])
            })



var customLabel0: some View{
 HStack {
  VStack(spacing: 10) {
    Text(labels[0])
      .foregroundColor(.black)
         Text(myArray[indexList[0]])
               .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
         }

       .foregroundColor(.white)
   }
   .frame(width: (width, height: height)
   .background(Color.gray)
   .cornerRadius(5)
}
```